# Check if list contains a string that matches closely

Tags: c#, regex, string, csv

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to implement the following scenario:

I have a list like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ValidTags = new List<string> {
  "ABC.XYZ",
  "PQR.SUB.UID",
  "PQR.ALI.OBD",
};
```

I have a huge CSV with multiple columns. One of the column is `tags`. This column either contains blank values, or one of the above values. The problem is, the tag column may contain values like "`ABC.XYZ?@`" i.e. the valid tags plus some extraneous characters. I need to update such columns with the valid tag, since they "*closely match*" one of our valid tags.

**Example:**

- if the CSV contains `PQR.ALI.OBD?` update it with the valid tag  `PQR.ALI.OBD`
- if the CSV contains `PQR.ALI.OBA`, this is invalid, just add suffix invalid and update it `PQR.ALI.OBA-invalid`.

I'm trying to figure out the best possible way to do this.

**My current approach is:**

1. Iterate through each column in CSV, get the tagValue
2. Now check if our tagValue contains any of the string from list
3. If it contains but is not exactly the same, update it with the value it contains.
4. If it doesnt "contain" any value from the list, add suffix-invalid.

*Is there any better/more efficient way to do this?*

Update:

The list has only 5 items, I have shown three here.
The extra chars are only at the end, and that's happening because people are editing those CSVs in excel web version and that messes up some entries.

My current code: (I'm sure there is a better way to do this, also new at C# so please tell me how I can improve this). I'm using [CSVHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/writing#writing-fields) to get CSV cells.

```
var record = csv.GetRecord<Record>();
string tag = csv.GetField(10); //tag column number in CSV is 10
/* Criteria for validation:
* tag matches our list, but has extraneous chars - strip extraneous chars and update csv
* tag doesn't match our list - add suffix invalid.*/
int listIndex = 0;
bool valid;
foreach (var validTags in ValidTags) //ValidTags is the enum above
{
    if (validTags.Contains(tag.ToUpper()) && !string.Equals(validTags, subjectIdentifier.ToUpper()))
    {
     valid = true;
     continue; //move on to next csv row.
    //this means that tag is valid but has some extra characters appended to it because of web excel, strip extra charts

    }
    listIndex++; 
    if(listIndex == 3 && !valid) { 
     //means we have reached the end of the list but not found valid tag 
     //add suffix invalid and move on to next csv row
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the extra characters always at the end?

Comment: Are those literally the only three items in the list? Or would any list items be subsets of other list items (for example `ABC.XYZ` and `ABC.XYZ.PQR`)?

Comment: Can you share your current approach code?

Comment: I will update the question with more details..thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as "closely match" with regular expressions. What you describe is fuzzy matching. *Sometimes* you can do it with regular expressions. A single character omission or transposition though is enough to break it. SQL Server's Integration services offer fuzzy grouping, lookups for data cleansing, which use fuzzy matching algorithms to calculate a matching score, allowing you to control what is matched.

Comment: the best basic fuzzy matching I've used is: levenshtein distance, check that out

Comment: @sniperd that's not the best. That's the *simplest*. It doesn't recognize transpositions as a single operation.  Damerau Levenshtein is better but still not as good as modern algorithms written specifically for fuzzy matching. Damerau was created in the 60s

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos best basic I've used.  The best I've used so far is the fuzzywuzzy module for python: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: @sniperd that's still only Levenshtein. It's also inappropriate if mismatches occur at the *end* of a string - Levenshteind would show a distance as long as the suffix and *drop* valid matches. Finally, It would be very slow if you have to calculate the distance for each word. There *are* techniques that reduce that time

Comment: @clever_bassi if the extra characters are at the end and you know the correct tags, why not do a simple `StartsWith`?

Comment: @clever_bassi as for Excel Online messing up anything, it doesn't. It's the users that do so but blame the computer as usual. You can prevent the problem at the source by using a drop-down combo list of allowed values for this column, [as shown here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-99b072ce-6240-428f-8736-7ea8d8749585). Drop down lists are an Excel feature for decades

Comment: @clever_bassi finally, why are you using *CsvHelper* to read *Excel* files? Use a library like EPPlus instead. You have to *convert* the Excel file to CSV first, then import it. The "invalid" characters may be Unicode characters lost during the conversion to ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that the extra characters are only at the end, and assuming that the original tag is still present before the extra characters, you could just search the list for each tag to see if the tag contains an entry from the list. If it does, then update it to the correct entry if it's not an exact match, and if it doesn't, append the "-invalid" tag to it.

Before doing this, we may need to first sort the list Descending so that when we're searching we find the closest (longest) match (in a case where one item in the list begins with another item in the list).

```
var csvPath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.csv";
var entriesUpdated = 0;

// Order the list so we match on the most similar match (ABC.DEF before ABC)
var orderedTags = ValidTags.OrderByDescending(t => t);
var newFileLines = new List<string>();

// Read each line in the file
foreach (var csvLine in File.ReadLines(csvPath))
{
    // Get the columns
    var columns = csvLine.Split(',');

    // Process each column
    for (int index = 0; index < columns.Length; index++)
    {
        var column = columns[index];

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: // tag column
                var correctTag = orderedTags.FirstOrDefault(tag =>
                    column.IndexOf(tag, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);

                if (correctTag != null)
                {
                    // This item contains a correct tag, so 
                    // update it if it's not an exact match
                    if (column != correctTag)
                    {
                        columns[index] = correctTag;
                        entriesUpdated++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // This column does not contain a correct tag, so mark it as invalid
                    columns[index] += "-invalid";
                    entriesUpdated++;
                }

                break;

            // Other cases for other columns follow if needed
        }
    }

    newFileLines.Add(string.Join(",", columns));
}

// Write the new lines if any were changed
if (entriesUpdated > 0) File.WriteAllLines(csvPath, newFileLines);
```